# Adding new tabs to TabControl

Tags: silverlight, addition, tabcontrol

What I want to do in this example is make the first tab of the tabcontrol disappear and add 2 new tabs dynamically. The new tabs appear but their 'Header' is not showing:

```
            ItemCollection ic = this.tabControl1.Items;
            TabItem firstTab = (TabItem)ic[0];
            firstTab.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
            newTab.HeaderTemplate = firstTab.HeaderTemplate;
            newTab.Header = newTab.Name = "test1";
            ic.Add(new TabItem());

            newTab = new TabItem();
            newTab.HeaderTemplate = firstTab.HeaderTemplate;
            newTab.Template = firstTab.Template;
            newTab.ContentTemplate = firstTab.ContentTemplate;
            newTab.Header = newTab.Name = "test2";
            ic.Add(new TabItem());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace both `ic.Add(new TabItem());` by `ic.Add(newTab)`

Like this:

```
TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
newTab.HeaderTemplate = firstTab.HeaderTemplate;
newTab.Header = newTab.Name = "test1";
ic.Add(newTab);

newTab = new TabItem();
newTab.HeaderTemplate = firstTab.HeaderTemplate;
newTab.Template = firstTab.Template;
newTab.ContentTemplate = firstTab.ContentTemplate;
newTab.Header = newTab.Name = "test2";
ic.Add(newTab);
```

Comment: Thank you. Well I hadn't seen it but it was obvious.